# Boost Compilation Issues

Tags: c++, boost, locking, compiler-errors, mutex

I am very very new to boost.  As I understand it, boost::mutex has both members lock() and unlock().  However I am getting the following error messages regarding the function that follows them.  I ran the 'sudo apt-get install libboost-dev' command within the same folder the source code.  This also my professors code which was given to the students.  I'm certain that it should be compiling correctly.  Any help would be great!

Error Messages:

> matrix.cc: In function ‘`void p_scalarproduct_t(int*, int*, int*, int, int, boost::mutex*)`’:
>
> matrix.cc:75: error: ‘`class boost::mutex`’ has no member named ‘`lock`’
>
> matrix.cc:77: error: ‘`class boost::mutex`’ has no member named ‘`unlock`’
>
> matrix.cc: In function ‘`int p_scalarproduct(int*, int*, int, int)`’:
>
> matrix.cc:91: error: ‘`bind`’ is not a member of ‘`boost`’

Code:

```
void p_scalarproduct_t(int* c, int* a, int* b, 
                       int s, int e, boost::mutex* lock)
{ 
    int tmp;

    tmp = 0;
    for (int k = s; k < e; k++)
        tmp += a[k] * b[k];

    lock->lock();
    *c = *c + tmp;
    lock->unlock();
}
```

Comment: What version of boost are you using? (Check `boost/version.hpp` to find out)

Comment: It says 1.34, but I know this isnt the latest version.  How could I update this?

Comment: @tpar44 : There's the problem; boost.thread was rewritten from scratch in 1.35. You can either reference the [documentation applicable to your version](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/libs/thread/doc/index.html) or you can [build the current version of boost from source](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html).

Comment: @tpar44 : Also, boost 1.34 is not only not the latest version, it's 4 years old now. As you can imagine, that's downright ancient in C++ years ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn okay one last question. WHen I install it from the source, what directory do I want to put it in?

Comment: @tpar44 : **Totally** up to you, but personally I'd remove your distribution's boost package then install to `/usr/include/` and `/usr/lib` (assuming you want to use the current boost release as your system boost installation).

Comment: @ildjarn that would allow me to run with just `#include<boost/mutex.hpp>` ?

Comment: @tpar44 : That depends on your `INCLUDE` environment variable, but most likely, yes.

Answer (score 1):

To lock a lock in boost, you need to pass it to the associated `scoped_lock`, in this case `boost::mutex::scoped_lock`. So to lock a lock `l_`, do this:

```
boost::mutex::scoped_lock l(l_)
```

Comment: but now I am confused.  The only thing that my professor put in the function boost::mutex* lock so what would I have to put in the lock()?

Comment: @tpar44    boost::mutex::scoped_lock local_lock(*lock)

Comment: @tpar44 the idea is to replace your lock->lock() with the scoped lock and remove the call to unlock. RAII will take care of unlocking the lock. If you need to limit the scope of your lock, put curly brackets {} around it: when the scoped_lock goes out of scope, the mutex is unlocked.